# JSX: render grid of images

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, reactjs

I have a list of 8 images that I want to render in a grid:

```
----- ----- ----- -----
|   | |   | |   | |   |
|   | |   | |   | |   |
----- ----- ----- -----
----- ----- ----- -----
|   | |   | |   | |   |
|   | |   | |   | |   |
----- ----- ----- -----
```

I do it with Bootstrap 3: rows and columns

```
<div className="row">

    <div className="col-xs-3">
        <img src="..." alt="..." />
    </div>

    <div className="col-xs-3">
        <img src="..." alt="..." />
    </div>

    <div className="col-xs-3">
        <img src="..." alt="..." />
    </div>

    <div className="col-xs-3">
        <img src="..." alt="..." />
    </div>
</div> <!-- END row -->

<div className="row">

    <div className="col-xs-3">
        <img src="..." alt="..." />
    </div>

    <div className="col-xs-3">
        <img src="..." alt="..." />
    </div>

    <div className="col-xs-3">
        <img src="..." alt="..." />
    </div>

    <div className="col-xs-3">
        <img src="..." alt="..." />
    </div>

</div> <!-- END row -->
```

So I need to loop through the list and for each 4 images I need to wrap them in a row. This serves as a spacer (20px) between rows.

In normal JS I would concatenate a string of markup while looping and using the iterator index as a condition.  But I can't do this in JSX as I understand.

So how do I do this with JSX?

Comment: I think I see the issue. You'll need to group all the images into arrays of 4, iterate over the group array, and inside the group iterate over the images.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept if one of the answers solved your question.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to group your images by 4. You can use the `groupBy` function below. It basically slices your images-array into groups of 4.
Next you need to iterate over your groups to create a row per group.
Then inside the group, you need to iterate over the images, column per image.

```
var images = ["https://baconmockup.com/300/200/","https://baconmockup.com/300/200/","https://baconmockup.com/300/200/","https://baconmockup.com/300/200/","https://baconmockup.com/300/200/","https://baconmockup.com/300/200/","https://baconmockup.com/300/200/","https://baconmockup.com/300/200/","https://baconmockup.com/300/200/","https://baconmockup.com/300/200/","https://baconmockup.com/300/200/","https://baconmockup.com/300/200/","https://baconmockup.com/300/200/","https://baconmockup.com/300/200/","https://baconmockup.com/300/200/"];
function render(){
  var imageGroups = groupBy(4, images);
  return (<div>
            {imageGroups.map(renderRow)}
          </div>);
}

function renderRow(group, index){
  return (<div className="row" key={index}>
            {group.map(renderColumn)}
          </div>);
}

function renderColumn(image, index){
  return (<div className="col-xs-3" key={index}>
            <img src={image} />
         </div>);
}

function groupBy(amountOfItemsPerGroup, items){
  var groups = [], 
    group, 
    total = items.length;
  for (var i=0; i < total; i += amountOfItemsPerGroup) {
    group = items.slice(i, i+amountOfItemsPerGroup);
    groups.push(group);
  }
  return groups;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  render(),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

See [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lanuru/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: For some reason jsbin is buggy with jsx, you may have to refresh the browser few times, or run with js few times.

Comment: Good suggestion but I dont think that I can use it because I need to animate the list when items are added and removed. I wrap "grouped" lists in a  ReactCSSTransitionGroup component. But problem is that im not added/removing from the grouped list but from the one in state... So react doesn't notice any changes and therefore nothing is animated...

Comment: That's too bad, I hope you find a solution with transitions working.

Comment: I will look into react-motion soon. That seems like a good route for animations in react :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, You do not need two row. Bootstrap will auto move 5th image to next line. Instead you should clearfix class.

```
    let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
     let rows= [];
         arr.forEach((val,index)=>{
        rows.push(<div key={index} className="col-xs-3">
            <img src="..." alt="..." />
        </div>
  })

    <div className="row">
    {
     rows
    }

 </div>
```

Comment: No it can be necessary because the cols are floated. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441689/if-more-than-12-columns-wrap-onto-a-new-line-automatically-do-we-really-need-to/26445839#26445839